# Casting DATE returns "Invalid Month" error

Tags: sql, oracle

My fiscal year starts on May 1 and ends Apr 30. I am trying to return the fiscal year start date using a CASE statement.

I.e.

```
CAST(
         CASE
             WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (GET_DATE, 'MM')) IN (11,
                                                           12,
                                                           5,
                                                           6,
                                                           7,
                                                           8,
                                                           9,
                                                           10)
             THEN
                   '05/01/'
                || TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (get_date, 'year'), 'YYYY'))
             WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (GET_DATE, 'MM')) IN (1,
                                                           2,
                                                           3,
                                                           4)
             THEN
                   '05/01/'
                || TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (get_date, 'year'), 'YYYY') - 1)
          END AS DATE)
```

I am getting "invalid month" when I use the cast but when I take it off, it defaults to number. Either way, i'm not getting the results I want.

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GET_DATE, -4), 'YYYY'), 4)` should do the same

Comment: You can't really cast a string to a date. You can just about get away with it if the string happens to be in the session's current `nls_date_format`, but it's better to use `to_date` with an explicit format mask (or approach the problem another way so you don't have to).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you, it worked beautifully! But if you don't mind, for the end date (trying to get 4/30/'next_year') I am getting the same year as the start date :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @CaiusJard's answer, you can get the start of the fiscal year with:

```
add_months(trunc(add_months(get_date, -4), 'YYYY'), 4)
```

- The `add_months(get_date, -4)` subtracts four months from the starting date, so a value in January to April will be adjusted to a date in September to December *of the previous year*. So for instance, 2018-03-11 will become 2017-11-11. But dates dates from May onwards will stay in the same year, so for instance 2018-07-04 becomes 2018-03-04.
- Then the `trunc(..., 'YYYY')` truncates that adjusted value to the first day of its year. So 2018-03-11 becomes 2017-11-11 which becomes 2017-01-01; and 2018-07-04 becomes 2018-03-04 which becomes 2018-01-01.
- Then the outer `add_months(..., 4)` adds four months back on to *that* adjusted value. So 2018-03-11 becomes 2017-11-11 which becomes 2017-01-01 which finally becomes 2017-05-01; and 2018-07-04 becomes 2018-03-04 which becomes 2018-01-01 which finally becomes 2018-05-01.

To get the last day of the fiscal year you can do the same thing but add an extra 12 months in the final calculation - which gives you the start of the *next* fiscal year - and then subtract one day:

```
add_months(trunc(add_months(get_date, -4), 'YYYY'), 16) - 1
```

Read more about the [`add_months()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html) and [`trunc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) functions, and about [date arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705), in the documentation.

Demo with dummy dates in a CTE to show the steps in the adjustment:

```
with your_table (get_date) as (
  select add_months(date '2018-01-15', level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 30
)
select get_date,
  add_months(get_date, -4) as adjusted_month,
  trunc(add_months(get_date, -4), 'YYYY') as adjusted_year,
  add_months(trunc(add_months(get_date, -4), 'YYYY'), 4) as start_date,
  add_months(trunc(add_months(get_date, -4), 'YYYY'), 16) - 1 as end_date
from your_table
order by get_date;

GET_DATE   ADJUSTED_M ADJUSTED_Y START_DATE END_DATE  
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2018-02-15 2017-10-15 2017-01-01 2017-05-01 2018-04-30
2018-03-15 2017-11-15 2017-01-01 2017-05-01 2018-04-30
2018-04-15 2017-12-15 2017-01-01 2017-05-01 2018-04-30
2018-05-15 2018-01-15 2018-01-01 2018-05-01 2019-04-30
2018-06-15 2018-02-15 2018-01-01 2018-05-01 2019-04-30
2018-07-15 2018-03-15 2018-01-01 2018-05-01 2019-04-30
...
2019-01-15 2018-09-15 2018-01-01 2018-05-01 2019-04-30
2019-02-15 2018-10-15 2018-01-01 2018-05-01 2019-04-30
2019-03-15 2018-11-15 2018-01-01 2018-05-01 2019-04-30
...
2020-02-15 2019-10-15 2019-01-01 2019-05-01 2020-04-30
2020-03-15 2019-11-15 2019-01-01 2019-05-01 2020-04-30
2020-04-15 2019-12-15 2019-01-01 2019-05-01 2020-04-30
2020-05-15 2020-01-15 2020-01-01 2020-05-01 2021-04-30
2020-06-15 2020-02-15 2020-01-01 2020-05-01 2021-04-30
2020-07-15 2020-03-15 2020-01-01 2020-05-01 2021-04-30
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ea7400fe39a7099102080102fb83aca)

---

As noted elsewhere in comments, your original code is erroring because `cast(<string> as date)` uses your session's NLS settings, and the string you are constructing does not match that setting. You could use `to_date()` instead of `case` so you can supply the expected format mask (see @alvalongo's answer!).

Comment: I got everything to work! I no longer have the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Just subtract 4 (four) months off your date and pull the year out of it (use trunc to reduce it to the year) then add 4 (four) months back on

```
SELECT 
  ADD_MONTHS(
    TRUNC(
      ADD_MONTHS( <yourdate> ,-4),
      'YEAR'),
  4) 
FROM DUAL;
```

As to why it works:

```
We have some example dates:              25-04-2009 13-07-2009
These are in the fiscal years beginning: 01-05-2008 01-05-2009
We subtract 4 months from the date:      25-12-2008 13-03-2009
We trunc down to the year start:         01-01-2008 01-01-2009
We add 4 months back on to get to May:   01-05-2009 01-05-2009
```

Why is it good/better than converting to string and back? Well, that's the reason right there. Dates are represented as a number, and this method keeps it as a number and works entirely off maths; adding, rounding and substracting. It's always better to avoid unnecessary data type conversions, because thy're slow, resource intensive and can introduce unexpected conversion errors

Using TRUNC with dates is one of the coolest things oracle does with dates that other databases just can't handle. Being able to take any date and TRUNC() it to the start of the year/month/day/hour/minute/weekday etc month is a great help in reports where events are logged to millisecond precision, but you want to summarise or work with them in terms of "number of things that happened this week/month" etc

Comment: This is the best method.

Comment: @Caius Jard, question is about START of fiscal year for any date between May-01 of any year and April-30 of next year, so you cann't not substract 5 (five)

Comment: The method is right, but it gives June not May; you need to subtract and add 4 months, not 5?

Comment: Yes, a nice man above told me 4 months and that worked perfectly! Now, I am having issues with the fiscal year end date not returning the next year but instead giving me the same year. so 4/30/2009 as end and 5/1/2009 as start.

Comment: @FatimaH. - you haven't shown how you're finding the end date. But you could use the same method, just go forward an extra year and back a day: `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(GET_DATE, -4), 'YEAR'), 16) - 1`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41357e7c51a8a21e7dc1bdf58d064c33).

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, you are right. I did not show it, but yes, it is the same method. I just could not figure out the logic of one more year, then subtracting a day. Thanks for your help, all of you!

Comment: Also, this is not to do with the question per se. But can you explain why we do -4, is that allowing it to go to May? I am just confused why we are using (-) and not (+)?

Comment: @FatimaH. - it's doing both + and -. If you subtract 4 months from a date in Jan-Apr 2018, it gives you a date in Sep-Dec 2017. So when you trunc that to the (calendar) year you get 2017-01-01. Then adding the 4 months back on pushes you forward to 2017-05-01. If your starting date is May-Dec 2018 then subtracting 4 months still leaves you in 2018, so the trunc give you 2018-01-01, and adding 4 months gives you 2018-05-01.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle, this get the Start of Fiscal Year for any date.

Just replace "sysdate" function with a variable of type DATE or a column name of type DATE:

```
select /* for Oracle */
       to_date(CASE 
                 WHEN extract(month from sysdate)<5 then
                        extract(year from sysdate)-1
                 ELSE 
                   extract(year from sysdate)
               end||'-05-01',
               'yyyy-mm-dd') as start_fiscal_year
from dual;
```

Testing on Oracle database using anonymous block:

```
Declare
 /*=========================================================================================
  --  objective: calculate Start fiscal date  
  --             Fisacal year starts on May 1 and ends April 30
  --
  --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426117/casting-date-returns-invalid-month-error-in-plsql
  --
  --  Database: Oracle
  --
  --  2018-09-20 alvalongo
  ==========================================================================================*/
  dtStart_date         date:=to_date('2018-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd');
  dtAny_date           date;
  dtStart_fiscal_date  date;
Begin
    dbms_output.put_line('I |ANY_DATE  |START_FISCAL_YEAR');
   for nuI in 0..24 loop
       dtAny_date:=add_months(dtStart_date,nuI);
       --
       select to_date(CASE 
                        WHEN extract(month from dtAny_date)<5 then
                             extract(year from dtAny_date)-1
                        ELSE 
                          extract(year from dtAny_date)
                      end||'-05-01','yyyy-mm-dd') as start_fiscal_year
       into dtStart_fiscal_date
       from dual;
       if extract(month from dtAny_date)=5 then
          dbms_output.put_line('--|----------|----------');
       end if;
       dbms_output.put_line(lpad(nuI,2)
                            ||'|'||to_char(dtAny_date         ,'yyyy-mm-dd')
                            ||'|'||to_char(dtStart_fiscal_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')
                           );
   End loop;
End;
/
```

Output using dbms_output buffer:

```
I |ANY_DATE  |START_FISCAL_YEAR
 0|2018-01-10|2017-05-01
 1|2018-02-10|2017-05-01
 2|2018-03-10|2017-05-01
 3|2018-04-10|2017-05-01
--|----------|----------
 4|2018-05-10|2018-05-01
 5|2018-06-10|2018-05-01
 6|2018-07-10|2018-05-01
 7|2018-08-10|2018-05-01
 8|2018-09-10|2018-05-01
 9|2018-10-10|2018-05-01
10|2018-11-10|2018-05-01
11|2018-12-10|2018-05-01
12|2019-01-10|2018-05-01
13|2019-02-10|2018-05-01
14|2019-03-10|2018-05-01
15|2019-04-10|2018-05-01
--|----------|----------
16|2019-05-10|2019-05-01
17|2019-06-10|2019-05-01
18|2019-07-10|2019-05-01
19|2019-08-10|2019-05-01
20|2019-09-10|2019-05-01
21|2019-10-10|2019-05-01
22|2019-11-10|2019-05-01
23|2019-12-10|2019-05-01
24|2020-01-10|2019-05-01
Total execution time 517 ms
```

Comment: That's a great improvement and simplification of the approach in the question; but Caius' approach still seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked for me. DATE is an inbuilt key word so we cannot use that as the column alias. I changed that to FS_START_DATE.

```
 SELECT SYSDATE,  TO_DATE(CASE
     WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM')) IN (11, 12, 5,6,7, 8,9, 10)
     THEN '05/01/' || TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'year'), 'YYYY'))
     WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM')) IN (1, 2, 3,4)
     THEN  '05/01/' || TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'year'), 'YYYY') - 1)
  END,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS FS_START_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

I am using TO_DATE function and this returns me 01-MAY-2018.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did have a variable similar to FS_START_DATE, the "as DATE" is for the CAST to convert the whole code into a DATE.

Comment: i edited the code to include TO_DATE function. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work, if you want to maintain the **CASE** statement

```
select CASE WHEN                               
MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) < 5 THEN                   
YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1    ELSE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
end
```

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle, which doesn't have `month()` or `year()` functions. You could do it with `extract()`, but alvalongo's answer is already showing that.